# Why would I participate in a stock exchange's opening and closing auctions?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, stock-exchanges, call-auction

During the trading day, stock exchanges function as continuous trading markets. The exceptions are the opening and closing auctions. Opening and closing auctions are call markets.

- As a small retail investor, what are the reasons I would want to participate in an opening or closing auction?
- What advantages do I get from placing Market-On-Open (MOO), Limit-On-Open (LOO), Market-On-Close (MOC), Limit-On-Close (LOC) orders that I would not get from market orders and limit orders placed during regular trading hours?
- Are the opening and closing auctions only useful to traders who want to transact large volumes that they are unable to get in the continuous double auction market?

Comment: Quite simply, people (you know, those "other" people, not smart people like us) are desperate to buy/sell at those times.  The thinking is that you can get the "price you want" then.  And, precisely what you say in "3".  (Recall that to begin with, real day traders would rather die than keep a position overnight, so there's a bit of dumping going on.)  You will hear people assert that the price discovered is more "real" in those two events.

Comment: Just BTW, for those who mystically believe in so-called candlesticks (Read Nison or the original Japanese), they believe that the actual "discovered opening" and "discovered closing" of a trading session which has an open and close, has mystical value.  (ie the entire point of a candlestick is that it shows you the supposedly-mystically-important open and close {with exactly the mechanism you ask about} of a trading session which has an open and close.) This was even more true (or supposedly true, or whatever) when it was guys yelling in a room.